# Woocommerce conditional show

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Have another issue, thing is - I'm trying to make a checkup of category and make positive or negative response with my woocommerce categories.
I want to exclude in example "accessories" category from my shop page, but I want to include only accessories in another custom page which is built by page builder, anyway so I'm trying to paste in functions.php code like this, but getting white page after saving.

Code:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {    
$tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );    
$tax_query[] = array(           
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',           
'field' => 'slug',           
'terms' => array( 'accessories' ), 
    if(is_product_category( 'accessories' ) = 1)           
    {             
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'         
    } else {             
    'operator' => 'IN'          
    return true;           
    }    
    );    
    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );}
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, missing something, but please put me in a right way how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Product Category is not "Category" but  it is "Taxonomy". So you can use "get_the_terms()" function in this.

Comment: @MujeebuRahman wow, I was trying to make it in difficult way, and obviously you gave me much easier way! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Use [WooCommerce shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) - `[products category="accessiories"]` to achieve this

There are lot of parameters avaliable to pass to the product list through the shortcode

More info can be seen [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#display-product-attributes)